# Where does rsyslog keep facility local0?

Tags: fedora, rsyslog

I added to rsyslog.conf a lines

```
ModLoad imudp
UDPServerRun 514
local0.* /var/log/dlink.log
```

With tcpdump I can see the packets from dlink somethimes local0 somethimes local1 even local2. Nothing appeared in /var/log/ dir. Which steps i missed to log my network device? I tried local1 local2 point to the same log file, but this didn't make the trick.

Comment: Did you restart rsyslog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the following statements:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

Note the `$` at the beginning.

Comment: Fine, question SOLVED after i get variables corrected.